# Had to use POST for GET job for security reasons, Is there any alternate approach to without compromising api naming conventions?

Tags: rest, post, get, naming-conventions, restful-url

We are using **POST /xxx/usage/get** instead of using **GET /xxx/usage** for security reasons, As per API naming conventions verbs are not allowed to be used in resource path. But we are using POST instead of GET to avoid sending some sensitive information over query param, What would be the best way to identify the URI has Get job??

**Option 1:** use GET method, since security is primary concern. its is avoided.
**Option 2:** While using POST, use naming convention to tell its actually a GET job without compromising naming convention. I am thinking of using **POST /xxx/usage/queries**.

Comment: I don't see how it is relevant, My question is based on naming convention.

Comment: I think you meant to address that comment to the answer...

Answer (score 0):

> we are using POST instead of GET to avoid sending some sensitive information over query param, What would be the best way to identify the URI has Get job??

You don't.

In REST, URI are opaque -- clients are not supposed to make any assumptions based on the spelling of the identifiers.  Any information encoded into the identifier is done at the server's discretion and for its own exclusive use.

When you communicate that a resource responds to POST messages (whether that be by documentation, hypermedia, or options), you are communicating a specific [messaging semantic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) that cannot be overridden by changing the spelling of the identifier.

As far as REST is concerned

```
POST /7fa070bc-4e98-4bd1-b525-d5564b918e4c
```

is perfectly fine.  Not as human readable as we might like, but human readability is optional.

You'll want to stick with the recommendations in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986); here, that really just means that any path segments should align with your link hierarchy.

Most spelling conventions for uri focus on identifying the noun -- what is the *integration resource* that handles this particular request.  Note that its the identifier for the resource, not the method -- if its suitable for GET, it is fine for POST as well, generally.

So you can replace

```
GET /xxx/usage?sensitive-information-here
```

with

```
POST /xxx/usage

sensitive-information-here
```

But

```
POST /xxx/usage/queries
```

is also fine; so you can go with that, so long as it doesn't violate your local spelling conventions.